# .htaccess rules for subdomain to force https on all pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have several sites as sub-domains with a main domain called site1.com. My main domain has a wildcard ssl certificate for `*.site1.com`. My subdomains can be referenced as `site2.site1.com`, `site3.site1.com` to `siteN.site1.com`. My main domain uses the certificate correctly and forces https on all pages, my subdomains only use https on the admin pages, I'm using a wordpress CMS or I can force the certificate to be used if I reference my sites as `https://site2.site1.com`, `https://site3.site1.com etc`. I want to get my subdomains running as `https://site2.com`. Currently my domain works as `http://site2.com` or `http://site1.site2.com`

PS: I have no access to the vhost file. Here is my .htaccess code for all my domains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^libwww-perl*"  block_bad_bots
Deny from env=block_bad_bots

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple plugin that did the job for me. This is what my .htaccess file looks like now for my sub-domain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# BEGIN WordPress

#RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^libwww-perl*"  block_bad_bots
Deny from env=block_bad_bots
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cant accept your answer as it didnt work. I tried this with a seperate subdomain without the plugin and it did the same thing. Im sorry man, I can upvote your answer but I cant accept it